# Super simple Auth0 usage with NO JS framework?

Tags: auth0, auth0-js

New to Auth0, so please forgive my ignorance.

After spending hours going through examples and docs for Auth0, I feel like I know less about it now than when I started. I'm not using any of the frameworks pointed to by the example/docs. I just want Auth0 to manage the user id/password login part of the site, and when a user signs in, return a unique id that I can match up to the user's data in a table.

Everything I'm seeing seems a lot more complicated that I would have guessed it could be.

Is there a way to pass the user id and password to a function in Javascript that returns a result code and unique id for a user when they sign-in? I presume that if I have a form with user id and password field and a button, I would use AJAX or something to send the sign in info, then await the response. That would indicate if the sign-in was valid, and provide a unique id (or use the passed user id to locate the user's info?)

Is there a *very simple* example I can take a look at to see how it's done?

Also, a lot of the terms used with Auth0 are unclear as to what they are used for, or where I would get the info to fill them out. Is there a glossary available?

Thanks!

Comment: The unique id you need is the `sub` on the auth0 access token (JWT). Thats the user’s identity. Is your application already integrated with auth0 or are you trying to setup the integration for the first time? Do you already have existing users and want to move to auth0 for logins? Why? What type of web application are you using - a single page application or a traditional web-server application?

Comment: If you need to learn more about topic, try to search for IETF OAuth 2.0/2.1 Framework, Grant Types and related flows; and then combine it with OpenID (OIDC). Many known flows are deprecated that is why important to know "what type of app" as asked. For SPA focus on Code flow with PKCE, etc. It would be helpful to understand that Auth0|Okta is company that provides Authorisation server which implements mentioned Framework, same as open source Keycloak, Spring Authorization Server and some others. It's complex work with many calls to different endpoints, so try to use Auth0 SDK with VanilaJS.

Comment: Auth0 with JS: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/01-login

Comment: You can also replicate these steps in JS: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/add-login-auth-code-flow

Comment: @VladimirVukanac Thanks for the links and info. Very helpful, and I was able to get the sample running on my local machine. How do I deploy it to my server? Copied everything up there, but no joy. Is there a step by step guide for this? I'm on a shared server. I am building an SPA.

Comment: @VladimirVukanac Another question, How difficult is using KeyCloak vs auth0/Okta? What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Focus first on client side. I did several Quickstart tutorials on Auth0 and they work nice, just follow each step. Keycloak is useful later. You need to deploy and configure it on your own.